# how to install sql 2008 after VS 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

after install VS 2012 I want to install sql server 2008 R2 but need SP1

when install sp1 give me this error
**A compatible version of Visual Studio 2008 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (ENU) product family, and is not compatible with any Express editions.**

Comment: go to link              http://sqlserverstore.blogspot.com/2012/01/another-version-of-microsoft-visual.html

Comment: Well, the first question that comes to mind is **What edition of VS 2012 did you install?** You said twice "VS 2012" without any more information.